# Animate CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am newer to cocos2d and preparing my demo game. I am moving a sprite from right to left using just a single image like a bird image moving from left to right. But I want to animate that sprite through various images so that it may look like a flying bird. I don't know how to accomplish that.

Here is my code:

```
    CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Target.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)]
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
    id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
    [target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Animating particular sprite You would require sprite-sheet to be there in your Resource. You can create the Sprite-sheet from either[Texture Packer](http://www.texturepacker.com/download/) OR [Zwoptex](http://zwopple.com/zwoptex/) Tools which I normally use.

Next you can implement the Below Code

```
    CCSpriteBatchNode *sheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"drawing1-i3.png"]; // Png File Name
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"drawing1-i3.plist"]; // Plist File Name
    [self addChild:sheet];

        //Generating the Animation 
    NSMutableArray *arr_anim =[NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i=1; i<30; i++) // i< number of frames in the plist File Name
    {
        NSString *str_fileNm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"drawing1%d.png",i];
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:str_fileNm];
        [arr_anim addObject:frame];
    }

    CCSprite *startAnim = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"drawing11.png"];
    [startAnim setPosition:ccp(150,150)];
    [self addChild:startAnim];

    //Starting the Animation 
    CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:arr_anim delay:0.15f];
    // id action =[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:YES]];
    id action =[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:NO];   
    [startAnim runAction:action];
```

I think it would help you for creating the Animations.

Comment: sprite sheet is not a requirement for an animation

Comment: The `startAnim` sprite should be added as a child of the batch node that way it only uses a single OpenGL call or a "batch draw".

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CCAnimation class.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_animation.html)

In particular, use methods like `animationWithFrames:` and supply your images as an array.